# Django 1.7 recursive query values?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am looking for a pythonic way to query something like this:

```
# Models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile_set')
    district = models.ForeignKey(District)
    ...


class District(models.Model):
    name : ...
```

I'd like to get a list of district (or pks) like what you get when use `values_list` method, but making the query to User Model. I've tried this:

```
User.objects.select_related('user_profile').values('user_profile_set__district__pk')
User.objects.all().values('user_profile_set__district__name')
User.objects.all().values_list('user_profile_set__district__name')
```

But nothing works, I am using django 1.7 (`depth` parameter is not longer available for `select_related` method). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Queries across relationships don't use the `_set` syntax. Try this:

```
User.objects.all().values('userprofile__district__name').distinct()
```

Comment: I use it as `related_name`. Sorry I didn't mentioned it. I have edited the question.

Comment: That should work, then. What do you get when you run the query?

Comment: If I run `User.objects.all().values('user_profile_set')` I get `[{'user_profile_set': 171L}, {'user_profile_set': 232L}, {'user_profile_set': 92L} ... ]` But if I run `User.objects.all().values('user_profile_set__district__name')` I get `[{'user_profile_set__district__name': None}, {'user_profile_set__district__name': None}, {'user_profile_set__district__name': None} ... ]`

Comment: What does `User.objects.all().values('user_profile_set__district__name').distinct()` return? It's expected that without adding a `distinct` parameter to the database query you'll get repeated elements.

Comment: It returns a list containing this: `{'user_profile_set__district__name': None}, ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to execute the query like this:

```
UserProfile.objects.values('district__name')
```

And if you need to query from an especified model instance:

```
user_profile.objects.filter(user=my_user).values('district__name')
```

Also if you are using `User.objects.all().values('user_profile_set__district__name')` and getting this output:

```
[{'user_profile_set__district__name': None},  
{'user_profile_set__district__name': None}, 
{'user_profile_set__district__name': None} ... ]
```

It might mean that your save method is not working correctly or at least for the name field, you might want to use the shell and query your District objects to verify if they have a name.